# Positioning DIVS

Tags: html, layout, position

I'm looking at having 3 divs one on top of the other with a small gap between them.

```
<div style="position:absolute; border:2px solid #000; top:40px;  width:300px; height:100px"></div>

<div style="position:absolute; border:2px solid #000; top:150px; width:300px; height:300px"></div>

<div style="position:absolute; border:2px solid #000; top:460px; width:300px; height:100px"></div>
```

This works and looks OK, however if the top or middle div grow in size then they could overlap the other div's.

Is there anyway to set it so div 2 will always be 10px away from div 1, and div 3 always 10px from div 2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add two divs in between given three divs like this.

```
<div style="position:relative; border:2px solid #000;  width:300px; height:100px"></div>
<div style="position:relative; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative; border:2px solid #000; width:300px; height:300px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative; border:2px solid #000; width:300px; height:100px"></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Arzs8/)